# $match with resumeAfter in mongodb changeStream

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Following is the sample code which I am using to watch updates on users collections. Storing resume token in redis. Whenever the changestream is stopped the token is stored and when the stream opens again it starts from there.

```
const watchMatch = [
    { $match: { 'fullDocument.watchIndex': {$gte: 0} } },
    { $addFields: { watchSource: 'watcher1' } }
];
const collection = db.collection('users');
const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline);
changeStream.on('change', next => {
    // process next document
    // Store/Update current resume token
    const resumeToken = "check if token object is available in redis";
    if (resumeToken) {
        changeStream.close();
        // Resume watch
        newChangeStream = collection.watch({ resumeAfter: resumeToken });
        newChangeStream.on('change', next => {
            // process next document
        });    
    }

});
```

But when the stream resumes it does not filter with match condition I have written in the main stream. So basically my question is how can I apply $match on changeStream with resumeAfter option if it is possible to do.

> Or can I get full document with resumeAfter?

Comment: Could you please provide feedback to the answer ? Thank you

Comment: Did not get a chance to test this, will update when I do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass pipeline when you resume the change stream along with resumeAfter option. Something like

```
newChangeStream = collection.watch(watchMatch,{ resumeAfter: resumeToken});
```

Comment: Damn man!! this was so straight forward and I didnt think about it. Thanks